# Deploy + desktop application + TFS 2017

Tags: deployment, release-management

I have a winForm application. I want to install it on the server every time the CI/CD happens. Later, after I install it(i don't know how to automate installation as well.), I want to run UI tests on it. What task should I add to my release management?

I only found web deployment when I researched. Since, mine is a desktop application, I need different build/release task. I could do it from vs2017(by right click project + publish)[image: setup files when published from vs2017, on my local system]
I want similar one from TFS 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to publish my desktop application on to the server. below is the article which explains the build tasks needed.
[Click here](http://blog.danskingdom.com/continuously-deploy-your-clickonce-application-from-your-build-server/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build with the publish profile. See [Publish profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?tabs=aspnetcore2x#publish-profiles).

In TFS using VS Build step with the MSBuild Arguments something like below:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.StagingDirectory)\\" /p:PublishProfile="YourPbulishProfile"
```

You can reference this article : [Using Web Deploy in Visual Studio Team Services Release Management](https://blog.ehn.nu/2016/03/using-web-deploy-in-visual-studio-team-services-release-management/)

---

To run coded UI tests from TFS.

Firstly, you need to run your agent as an [interactive process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents#account). Regarding how to deploy an agent on windows, please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows).

Secondly, add your coded UI tests project into TFS version control.

Last, create a build definition to use [Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment) task and [Run Functional Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/run-functional-tests) task to run the tests.

Reference below articles:

- [Continuous integration, test, and deployment tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/example-continuous-testing?view=vsts)
- [Deploy a Desktop App from TFS to VM for Coded UI Test.](https://dotblogs.com.tw/mystic_pieces/2017/06/16/163023)